Custom Credential Provider Not Showing in Sign-In Options on Locked LogonUI
I’ve developed a custom credential provider for Windows 11 and followed these steps:
Successfully built the credential provider, which generated a DLL under x64/Debug.
Moved the DLL to the System32 directory.
Registered the credential provider using a registry file.
However, when I lock the machine and go to the LogonUI screen, I don't see the "Sign-In Options" button. My custom credential provider should appear under this option, but it doesn’t show up at all.
Here’s what I’ve already checked:
DLL Placement: Ensured that the DLL is correctly placed in C:\Windows\System32.
Registry Entries: Verified that the registry keys were added correctly under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers and that they point to the correct CLSID and DLL path.
Build Configuration: The DLL is built in x64/Debug mode, matching the system architecture.
Signatures and Security: My DLL is not signed. Could this be the issue?
Questions:
What could be causing the "Sign-In Options" button not to appear?
Are there additional steps or checks required to ensure that my custom credential provider is activated and recognized by the system?
Is there a requirement for the DLL to be signed or any specific permissions needed?
Any insights or additional steps to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.

hire developer(s) who can write and debug this
